# How to call an array in stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

May I know on how to call an array in stored procedure? I tried to enclosed it with a bracket to put the column_name that need to be insert in the new table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE data_versioning_nonull(new_table_name VARCHAR(100),column_name VARCHAR(100)[], current_table_name VARCHAR(100))
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE ('CREATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(new_table_name) || ' AS SELECT ' || quote_ident(column_name) || ' FROM ' || quote_ident(current_table_name));
END $$;

CALL data_versioning_nonull('sales_2019_sample', ['orderid', 'product', 'address'], 'sales_2019');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using [`execute format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) lets you replace all the `quote_ident()` with `%I` placeholders in a single text instead of a series of concatenated snippets. `%1$I` lets you re-use the first argument.
2. It's best if you use `ARRAY['a','b','c']::VARCHAR(100)[]` to explicitly make it an array of your desired type. `'{"a","b","c"}'::VARCHAR(100)[]` works too.
3. You'll need to convert the array into a list of columns some other way, because when cast to text, it'll get curly braces which are not allowed in the column list syntax. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DsnUCGjs)
4. It's not a good practice to introduce random limitations - PostgreSQL doesn't limit identifier lengths to 100 characters, so you don't have to either. The default limit is [63 bytes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html), so you can go way, way longer than 100 characters ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rpd68aQx)). You can switch that data type to a regular [`text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html). Interestingly, exceeding specified varchar length [would just convert it to unlimited varchar](https://dbfiddle.uk/5kj6So6y), making it just syntax noise.

[DBFiddle online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5S-JFW-4)

```sql
CREATE TABLE sales_2019(orderid INT,product INT,address INT);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE data_versioning_nonull(
  new_table_name     TEXT,
  column_names       TEXT[], 
  current_table_name TEXT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  list_of_columns_as_quoted_identifiers TEXT;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(name),',')
  INTO list_of_columns_as_quoted_identifiers
  FROM unnest(column_names) name;
  
  EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %1$I.%2$I AS SELECT %3$s FROM %1$I.%4$I',
                   current_schema(),
                   new_table_name,
                   list_of_columns_as_quoted_identifiers,
                   current_table_name);
END $$;

CALL data_versioning_nonull(
  'sales_2019_sample', 
  ARRAY['orderid', 'product', 'address']::text[], 
  'sales_2019');
```

5. Schema awareness: currently the procedure creates the new table in the default schema, based on a table in that same default schema - above I made it explicit, but that's what it would do without the `current_schema()` calls anyway. You could add `new_table_schema` and `current_table_schema` parameters and if most of the time you don't expect them to be used, you can hide them behind procedure overloads for convenience, using `current_schema()` to keep the implicit behaviour. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/MpqLwTSf)

Answer (score 0):

First, change your stored procedure to convert selected columns from array to csv like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE data_versioning_nonull(new_table_name VARCHAR(100),column_name VARCHAR(100)[], current_table_name VARCHAR(100))
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE ('CREATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(new_table_name) || ' AS SELECT ' || array_to_string(column_name, ',') || ' FROM ' || quote_ident(current_table_name));
END $$;
```

Then call it as:

```
CALL data_versioning_nonull('sales_2019_sample', '{"orderid", "product", "address"}', 'sales_2019');
```

Comment: Error :( tho that three in array are the existing columns in the sales_2019 table

`ERROR:  column "{"orderid", "product", "purchaseaddress"}" does not exist`